# How can I replace default "Slick Carousel" auto-generated Previous-Next arrows buttons manually?

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

Basically I need to use my own buttons rather than using the arrows that [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) plugin generates automatically.
 I've made my own buttons which should toggle between slides. Take the following markup as an example:

```
<button type="button" class="slick-next left-arrow"></button>
<button type="button" class="slick-prev right-arrow"></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are options that plugin will use for its arrows. You have to pass your custom arrow to plugin's options.

```
var $prev = $('.slick-prev.right-arrow');
var $next = $('.slick-next.left-arrow');
$('.multiple-items').slick({
  prevArrow: $prev,
  nextArrow: $next
  // other option
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmo50w7n/1093/)

Comment: Thanks for your help and attention, I appreciate you a lot, but I want to use those buttons in place out of slide container.

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani So you can pass jQuery selector to options.

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani Can u provide me a demo (jsfiddle)?

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution is correct, but it seems that have to add `arrows: true,`because my problem was  solved when I remove `arrows: false,` option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139887/discussion-between-alex-and-mojtaba-reyhani).